# The byte equivalent to cut the socket link

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, java-io

Normally when I use

```
r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
```

then I use

```
int nextChar = 0;
while ((nextChar=r.read()) != -1) 
{   

}
```

Now I am going to use byte level

```
r = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
```

so the first byte I read is this

```
try {
    while(true){
        if (r.readByte() != 0x7E) // start byte
        {
            // ah oh, something went wrong!!
            receivedSocketConn1.close();
            return;
        }

        int bodyLen = r.readUnsignedShort();       // message body nature (body length)

        byte serialNum1 = r.readByte();// message serial number
        byte[] messageBody = new byte[20];    // message body
        r.readFully(messageBody);

        if (r.readByte() != 0x7E) // end byte
        {
            // ah oh, something went wrong!!
            receivedSocketConn1.close();
            return;
        }
    }
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)  
{ 
    System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException has been caught");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}  
catch (IOException ex)  
{ 
    System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
finally
{
    try 
    {
        if ( w != null ) 
        {
            w.close();
            r.close();
            receivedSocketConn1.close();
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("MyError:w is null in finally close");
        }
    }
}
```

You see it always goes into the `finally` block after I do the `7e`, thereafter it cuts the link.  I would like to keep the link for some time. But before that, I want to run a `for` loop for the look for the `-1` in this scenario.  How to I implement that?

Comment: You want to look for end of stream *before* looking for 0x7E?

Comment: Yes EJP I need the equivalent of -1 in this method? I need to start reading up from 7E to 7E that will be my full data but i need to maintain the link.

Comment: Why this post down vote what is wrong in it ? I really dont see any mistake I have shown my effort what I have done and where I am stucked

Comment: The 0x7E must in the nature of things arrive either before end of stream or not at all. What you're asking doesn't make sense, and has not been adequately motivated. I don't see what 'maintain the link' has to do with it.

Comment: What I am asking is it there method to check for -1 like how I do when I am using r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

Comment: Yes the 0x7E must arrive in nature before the end of stream that is true.

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense. The question at the moment is why you want to read to end of stream before handling any of the data in it.

Comment: What I want to is that I need to maintain the connect so I want to have the end of the stream reached or not else my memory usage will go up with the thread being hold up

Comment: 'Maintain the connect' has nothing to do with whatever you're asking here.  There is no reason why you can't handle every byte as it arrives. Compilers do it: you can too. Suppose you tell us what your *actual* problem is? NB Your title is also meaningless.

Comment: Your further code explains nothing, and neither does this waffle about 'maintain the connect', and you still can't read data after end of stream. Surely this is obvious? What we need to know is what *problem* you're trying to solve. At present there isn't one.

Comment: Ok at present it goes into the finally block and does the w.close and r.close and receivedSocketConn1.close(); so the link is closed?

Comment: My question is I would like to not close the it till I get to end of the stream or device initiate a close?

Comment: So you caught an exception? if so, *what* exception? Or you just reached the `finally` block as a result of the `return` statement? **What is your question?** There are plenty of people here who can answer it, but there is nothing to answer yet, despite a lot of commentary.

Comment: Nope I dont want it got into the finally but to wait for some time for more data to come in? Is that clearer?

Comment: I dont reach the finally block due to the return statement but after the last 7e is captured. So it goes as per normal. I would like to wait one way is I say while(true) but then when will that become false ?

Comment: So keep reading and don't return until end of stream has been reached. *After* you recognise your 0x7E etc. Is this a mystery? But *why* do you think you need to read until end of stream?

Comment: So I have update with while(true) will there be consequence on memory usage and will it every become false?

Comment: I have asked you at less four times why you think you need to read to end of stream here. If you're not going to take any notice of the responses you get, it is difficult to understand why you're posting here at all.

Comment: I need to read the end of the stream to know where and when to go into finally block.

Comment: Another thing I would like to ask is it ok for me to have the while(true) loop at the very top?

Comment: @user5313398: `DataInputStream` throws an exception when the socket is closed.  And yes, the `while` loop is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle `-1` in this situation.

If you read the documentation, it says:

[`InputStream::read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())

> Returns:
>   the next byte of data, or **-1 if the end of the stream is reached**.

[`DataInputStream::readByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readByte())

> Throws:
>   **EOFException - if this input stream has reached the end**.
>   IOException - the stream has been closed and the contained input stream does not support reading after close, or another I/O error occurs.

The same goes for all of the `DataInputStream` reading methods.

So, all you have to do is read values from the `DataInputStream` normally and let it throw an exception if the socket gets closed by the peer.  You are already doing exactly that (`EOFException` extends `IOException` and will be caught in your `catch (IOException ex)` block).  You are over-thinking the problem.

That being said, if reading the `0x7E` byte is throwing an exception (which `readByte()` call is failing?  Which exception is being thrown?), then you are doing something wrong.  For instance, this question is based on [code I gave you yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39734000/65863) for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732170/), but the code you have shown in this question is incomplete based on the earlier code.  That omission would easily cause the second `if (r.readByte() != 0x7E)` to evaluate as false and close the connection.

Try something more like this instead:

```
w = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
r = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

try
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (r.readByte() != 0x7E) // start byte
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect start byte detected");

        int messageID = r.readUnsignedShort();     // message ID
        int bodyLen = r.readUnsignedShort();       // message body nature (body length)
        byte[] phoneNum = new byte[6];
        r.readFully(phoneNum);                     // device phone number
        int serialNum = r.readUnsignedShort();     // message serial number
        byte[] messageBody = new byte[bodyLen];    // message body
        r.readFully(messageBody);
        byte checkCode = r.readByte();             // check code

        if (r.readByte() != 0x7E) // end byte
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect end byte detected");

        // TODO: validate checkCode if needed...
        // ... 
        // if (checkCode is not valid)
        //    throw new RuntimeException("Bad checkCode value");

        // process message data as needed...
    }
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)  
{ 
    System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException has been caught");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}  
catch (EOFException ex)  
{ 
    System.out.println("Socket has been closed");
}  
catch (IOException ex)  
{ 
    System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (RuntimeException ex)
{ 
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
finally
{
    w.close();
    r.close();
    receivedSocketConn1.close();
}
```

Comment: yes I have put the while(true) ready like your suggestion. Yes you are right I am kind of over thinking and got mixed up with InputStream::read(). Another question I have do I need to setup this receivedSocketConn1.setSoTimeout(60000); for this codes or eventually the socket will get closed?

Comment: That depends on how often you are expecting to receive messages.  `setSoTimeout(60000)` will cause any read operation to throw an exception if no bytes are received for 1 minute. That would be a good thing to do in between reading the two `0x7E` bytes of a single message, since it shouldn't take 1 minute to receive the whole message.  But that might not be a good thing to do in between different messages if it takes more than 1 minute for a new message to be sent.

Comment: I dont quite get you here "But that might not be a good thing to do in between different messages if it takes more than 1 minute for a new message to be sent. "?

Comment: Think about it.  If you set the timeout to 1 minute, then receive a complete message, then another message is not sent for 2 minutes, you will get a timeout error before the second message is sent.